# Parent data not updated when using sync in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I've build a component named `Turno` (a work shift). I have some kind of calendar, for every day I have more instance of `Turno`.

If I book myself to a shift then I need to add my name in the shift, but reactivity seems not to work, parent object (with all shifts) doesn't update. I've also added `.sync` to property.

Shift template:

```html
    <div v-for="mansione in turno.mansioni">
        <v-row class="ma-0 pa-0 align-end">
            <v-col class="ma-0 pa-0" cols="8">
                <div class="caption font-weight-bold nome_mansione">{{ mansione.nome.toLowerCase() }}
                    <span class="caption">(Min. {{ mansione.min }})</span>
                </div>
            </v-col>
            <v-col class="ma-0 pa-0 text-right" cols="4">
                <div class="caption font-weight-bold nome_mansione">
                    <pulsante-generico :small="true" icon="mdi-account-plus" color="orange" @click="aggiungiPersona(turno,mansione)"/>
                </div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <hr class="mt-0">
        <div v-for="milite in mansione.militi" class="ma-2" style="line-height: 0.8rem">
            {{ milite.cognome }} {{ milite.nome }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

After a shift book (this should make reactivity? After this nothing changes, parent object is not affected):

```js
    turniService.prenotaTurno(prenotazione).then(d => {
        this.$emit("update:turno", d || this.turno)
        this.close()
    })
```

Props in shift component:

```js
    props: {
        turno: {
          type: Object,
          default: () => {
            return {
              dataInizio: null,
              dataFine: null,
              id: 0,
              tipo: "",
              mansioni: []
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

In the parent I render shifts like this:

```html
    <v-col v-for="day in dati.giorni">
        <DatiGiornoCalendario :day="day.giorno"/>
        <Turno v-for="(turno, i) in day.turni"
                :turno.sync="turno"
        />
    </v-col>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `turno` variable in `<Turno v-for="(turno, i) in day.turni" :turno.sync="turno" />` is a **local variable** in the loop

Use this instead: `<Turno v-for="(turno, i) in day.turni" :turno.sync="day.turni[i]" />`